# Gitlab CI - deploy to Heroku and run migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Rails App hosted on gitlab.com, and I am configuring it to deploy to heroku following this guide: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-ruby-application-to-heroku.html. It works fine.

My question is, how can I run migrations every time I deploy to heroku? When deploying via CLI I would usually do:

```
git push heroku master && heroku run rake db:migrate
```

but using gitlab-ci.yml I have no clue on how to do this...

Comment: Can you share what gitlab-ci.yml did you end up with?

Comment: I ended up using the example of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the full power of the Heroku CLI in your GitLab CI process (including having the build fail if a migration fails for whichever reason), you can also try this approach which will install the Heroku CLI and deliver status codes of your Heroku commands back to GitLab, as well as, of course, the command line output. Using `heroku run` without credentials on the commandline require the `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable to be set to a key which has access to the app in question.

```
before_script:
  - echo "deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list
  - wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y heroku-toolbelt
  - gem install dpl

stages:
  - deploy

test_on_heroku:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=my_heroku_app --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    - heroku run <your command here> --exit-code --app my_heroku_app
```

I actually run my tests on an Heroku instance to be sure, the environment is exactly the same. This is where this comes in real handy.

Comment: This saved my sanity, I'm not comfortable with the accepted answer since the old API is EOL soon.

Comment: Things change fast on the internet. :-)

Answer (score 8):

**The information in this answer may be out of date. Please see both answers below, and remember to upvote the answers that are up to date to help future visitors.**

here is a sample .yml I have that runs my tests then pushed to Heroku stage (for master branch pushes) or production (for tags pushes)

```
image: "ruby:2.3"

test:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install -j $(nproc) --without production
  - bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rails RAILS_ENV=test

staging:
  type: deploy
  environment: staging
  script:
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  - "curl -n -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/$HEROKU_STAGING_APP_NAME/ps -H \"Accept: application/json\" -H \"Authorization: Bearer ${HEROKU_API_KEY}\" -d \"command=bundle exec rails db:migrate\""
  only:
  - master

production:
  type: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  - "curl -n -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME/ps -H \"Accept: application/json\" -H \"Authorization: Bearer ${HEROKU_API_KEY}\" -d \"command=bundle exec rails db:migrate\""
  only:
  - tags
```

Comment: The command in `bundle exec rails db:migrate` should be  `rake` instead of `rails`. Other than that it seems to be ok. Thanks!

Comment: oh sorry for that. I am running Rails 5 which has moved all the rake commands into rails. :-)

Comment: maybe not all rake but tasks and tests. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#use-bin-rails-for-running-tasks-and-tests

Answer (score 7):

To update @huesforalice's answer, this would also work for the new Heroku CLI, which replaced Heroku Toolbelt in November 2016:

```yaml
before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install apt-transport-https
  - echo "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list
  - wget -O- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y heroku
  - gem install dpl

staging:
  type: deploy
  variables:
    HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
    - heroku run rails db:migrate --exit-code --app $HEROKU_STAGING_APP
  only:
    - master

production:
  type: deploy
  variables:
    HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
    - heroku run rails db:migrate --exit-code --app $HEROKU_PRODUCTION_APP
  only:
    - tags
```

Answer (score 1):

To further improve @huesforalice and @Jimmy Bosse 's answers - If you want to

- avoid putting Heroku CLI installation in the global `before_script` but only use it in the deployment stages
- at the same time, avoid copying and pasting the installation snippet into different stages

You can do something like this using YAML anchors to DRY up

```yaml
before_script:
  # the global before_script
  - gem install bundler --no-document
  - bundle check || bundle install --jobs $(nproc)

.deployment_before_script: &deployment_before_script
  before_script:
    - echo "deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list
    - wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y heroku-toolbelt
    - gem install dpl

# other stages...

staging:
  stage: deploy
  <<: *deployment_before_script
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY_STAGING
    - heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate --exit-code --app $HEROKU_APP_STAGING
  only:
    - master

production:
  stage: deploy
  <<: *deployment_before_script
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY_STAGING
    - heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate --exit-code --app $HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION
  when: manual
  only:
    - tags
```